# Error for slash commands. How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hey I am getting this when I do:

```js
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
```

Here is the error:

[Click me to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiB86.png)

Any fix for this error or packages?

Comment: You most likely need to update node.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade your Node.js version.

You're using a version of Node.js that doesn't support the `??` operator, which the version of Discord.js you're using does require.

[The first version to support that operator is 14.0.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator#browser_compatibility)

Comment: I did. I use replit

Comment: If replit doesn't support Node 14.0, then you'll need to use an older version of the package, or host your code elsewhere.

Comment: How can I check?

Comment: I googled "replit node 14" and found https://blog.replit.com/nix ... good luck!

Comment: How to I update node.js?

Comment: Try https://dev.to/arnavkr/updating-node-js-to-16-in-replit-1ep0 @Gamer1

Comment: Did not work...

Answer (score 2):

I did in a .replit file:
run = "npm i node@14.0.0"
It updated.
Thanks for all your help!